# variable sum in php

Tags: php, sum

I am trying to count sum of the variable totale in the code below:

```
$product_string = rtrim($proformat, ",");
$fullAmount = 0;
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_string);
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {
    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value);
    $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0];
    $product_name = $id_quantity_pair[1];
    $product_price= $id_quantity_pair[2];
    $product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[3];
    $total = $product_price * $product_quantity;
```

I tried this code but it did not work

```
$cartTotal = $total + $cartTotal;
```

Comment: _"but it did not work"_ what does that mean exactly? What happened? Any errors? Where does `$cartTotal` come from?

Comment: totale = 1;
totale = 2.
totalte = 3.
the result is  3 not 6

Answer (score 0):

You have to update $cartTotal on each pass of the loop:

```
$product_string = rtrim($proformat, ",");
$cartTotal = 0;
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_string);
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {
    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value);
    $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0];
    $product_name = $id_quantity_pair[1];
    $product_price= $id_quantity_pair[2];
    $product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[3];

    $cartTotal += $product_price * $product_quantity;

}
```

Where this:

```
$cartTotal += $product_price * $product_quantity;
```

Is actually an abbreviation of this:

```
$cartTotal = $cartTotal + ($product_price * $product_quantity);
```